# empty clickstreams in J2EE webapp - what is the cause?

Tags: jakarta-ee, opensymphony

I've added Opensymphony Clickstreams to my Java 6/Tomcat webapp, and created an interface for administrators to view the collected metadata.  What I don't understand is that sometimes, in addition to the usual streams, there are 'null' streams in the ServletContext.  These have all-empty values, for example:

```
Initial Referrer: null
Hostname: null
Session ID: 73537910A647115A403A7690D1F69DD2
Bot: No
Stream Start: Tue Oct 01 02:48:11 BST 2013
Last Request: Tue Oct 01 02:48:11 BST 2013
Session Length: 
# of Requests: 0
```

can anyone tell me what these empty Streams represent and how they are caused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these are being caused by Bots which are not identified (yet) in the Clickstream framework.